# MOSFET - calculating heat produced by MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, thermal

from the datasheet which one should I use? Thermal Junction to Case or Thermal Junction to Ambient?

Tj= Ta + Pd * Rth(j-c)

or

Tj= Ta + Pd * Rth(j-a)

when I use Rth(j-a), Tj become way too high, near TjMax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Rth(j-c) you either have to know the maximum case temperature or you have to add the thermal resistance of an external heat sink (case to heat sink + heat sink to ambient) and the maximum Ta.

So, you would use  Rth(j-a). If you are getting too high a Tj using  Rth(j-a) at the maximum Ta then you require a different package or a heat sink.

Don’t forget to account for switching losses and the large increase in Rds(on) at high temperatures and ensure you have sufficient gate drive voltage to get guaranteed Rds(on).

Comment: I already use Rds(on) at high temperature and Pd total (conduction losses, switching losses, dead time losses). Current at 30% mosfet can handle.